# What is the "< >" operator when accessing object methods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm coming from Python and don't understand the following syntax in C#:

```
Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Textures");
```

I'm instantiating a list of sprite objects and setting it to the output of `Resources.LoadAll()`.

What is the `< >` operator?

I'm trying to look it up, the proper name would help.

Comment: It's generics - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: @Valentin: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."

Comment: @Serlite it is actually already being used as a dupe target: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115434/what-is-generics-its-uses-and-application

Answer (score 1):

It's how you specify the type for that method. LoadAll has a generic return type and it needs to know the type that it is going to return. You do this with < >. I hope that helps.