# what is this syntax doing?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is generics in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560890/what-is-generics-in-c)

```
public class MyNewClassMapper < EntityContainer, ModelContainer > 
   : BaseClassContainerMapper < EntityContainer, ModelContainer >
{

}
```

I have the above code in my app. Could not find the link in MSDN which explains about the class declarations shown above. Added white space around for each angle brackets to make this post readable.
Please help.
Smith

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: looks like a standard generic class definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic class `MyNewClassMapper` that has generic type parameters `EntityContainer` and `ModelContainer` and inherits from generic class<sup>1</sup> `BaseClassContainerMapper` with these same parameters.

*<sup>1</sup> Could also be an interface, though it doesn't look like it in this case, based on name.*

Answer (score 0):

The `MyNewClassMapper<EntityContainer, ModelContainer>` is inherting from `BaseClassContainerMapper < EntityContainer, ModelContainer >`

the `<EntityContainer, ModelContainer>` are the type arguments

Please read more on information for Generic classes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is defining a class (MyNewMapperClass) that is derived from a base class (BaseClassContainerMapper).

The classes themselves are used to map one object type to another.