# What do the <> mean?

Tags: c#, .net

For example if you make a list the syntax will be `aList<int>` or `IEnumrable<int>`.  Is it just saying the data type?  Is there more to it than that?

When I look online for the answer to this question the results are always for operators like > greaterthan < lessthan symbols.  That is why I am asking it here.

Comment: It marks the type as a generic type.  Look for information on generic types in c#

Comment: [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) - read it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are generics in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560890/what-are-generics-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They denote a "Generic" type
So the keyword you want to be searching for is "C# Generics"
That will tell you all you need to know. Shout if you have further questions